# How can I press the subscribe button? (VBA)

Tags: vba

I'm trying to press the subscribe button of youtube but looks like it's impossible..

I tried this:

```
WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("subscribe-button").InvokeMember("click")
```

I also tried various codes but nothing really works.

any solution?

Comment: I'm searching for 2 hours already, tried many different codes and nothing works! I already said that, otherwise I wouldn't be here.

Comment: Your question is unanswerable anyway. See [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: what are the different codes that you tried?

Comment: finding all div elements and then by class, but I already solved the problem. I just had to inspect with IE, which has different code..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a working example using IE.

```
Const className As String = "yt-uix-button yt-uix-button-size-default yt-uix-button-has-icon no-icon-markup yt-uix-subscription-button yt-can-buffer yt-uix-servicelink yt-uix-button-subscribe-branded"

Sub ClickSubcribe()
    Dim ie As Object: Set ie = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    With ie
        'Easter Egg?
        .navigate "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"
        .Visible = True
        Do Until .readystate = 4: DoEvents: Loop
        .document.getElementsByClassName(className)(0).Click
    End With

End Sub
```

In reviewing this I couldn't find the ID **`subscribe-button`** with Internet Explorer, but I did with Chrome. If you are using Selenium you may want to make sure that element actually exists first, or that the WebDriver is setup to use Chrome.

Comment: I was inspecting with Chrome but VB uses IE, I didn't pay attention to that :P after inspecting with IE I could make it working! Thx for your advice!